# Из-за Rigidbody2D на игроке, появляется маленькая щель между Player и Ground?

Tags: c#, unity3d

До запуска 2 объекта на одном уровне Y(Слева Player, справа обычный спрайт)

[image: До запуска]

После запуска 2 объекта на разном уровне Y(Слева Player, справа обычный спрайт)

[image: После запуска]

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте размер коллайдер по Y меньше, допустим на 0.98. Вы можете изменить размер либо на персонаже, либо на полу.